How to run cell and stay on it in a Jupyter Notebook on VS code?
I am using Jupyter Motebook on a Mac (silicon). 
I would like to run a cell and stay on it (keep working on it / debugging etc.). But It keeps jumping to the next cell (or creating a new cell below).
I tried to play around with the shortcuts (going to "Code">>"Settings">>"Keyboard Shortcuts" and searching for "Jupyter:run". 
The current status is that if I press Shift+Enter, the cell is ran and I am "jumping" to the next cell; and if I press Ctrl+Enter the cell is ran and I am "jumping" to a new cell below it.
I tried changing Jupyter: Run Cell, Jupyter: Run Current Cell, Jupyter: Run Current Cell And Advance, Jupyter: Runcurrentcellandaddbelow - but it did not solve the issue.
I saw this thread, but I am searching for the opposite option.

I think you're looking for "Notebook: Execute Cell" (notebook.cell.execute), which is bound to ctrl+alt+Enter by default.
ctrl+enter should actually also stay on the same cell by default by running notebook.cell.executeAndFocusContainer but focuses the container instead of staying within the cell editor. You can run "Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting" to find out what command you are actually running and adjust your keybindings as necessary.
